# Unexpected result with right shift after bitwise negation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I expected that below code will output `10` because `(~port)` equal to `10100101`
So, when we right shift it by `4` we get `00001010` which is `10`.
But the output is `250`! Why?

```
int main()
{
    uint8_t port = 0x5a;
    uint8_t result_8 =  (~port) >> 4;
    //result_8 = result_8 >> 4;

    printf("%i", result_8);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

C promotes `uint8_t` to `int` before doing operations on it. So:

1. `port` is promoted to signed integer `0x0000005a`.
2. `~` inverts it giving `0xffffffa5`.
3. An arithmetic shift returns `0xfffffffa`.
4. It's truncated back into a `uint8_t` giving `0xfa == 250`.

To fix that, either truncate the temporary result:

```
uint8_t result_8 = (uint8_t)(~port) >> 4;
```

mask it:

```
uint8_t result_8 = (~port & 0xff) >> 4;
```

or xor it (thanks @Nayuki!):

```
uint8_t result_8 = (port ^ 0xff) >> 4;
```

Comment: you're right but i think C doesn't promote only `uint8_t` but also `unsigned char` because i tested it with `unsigned char` too and got the same result! Am i right?

Comment: `uint8_t` is, very likely, a synonym of `unsigned char` on your system. The promotion rules apply to all integral types smaller than `int`.

Comment: Or explicitly only flip the low 8 bits: `result = (port ^ 0xFF) >> 4;`

Comment: Does C++ do that too?

Comment: @TomášZato: Yes. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions

Comment: "An arithmetic shift returns 0xfffffffa" --> note this in _implementation-defined_.   C11dr §6.5.7 5